# Variable substitution of multiline list of strings in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to substitute the list in the following code:

```
kategori NOT IN ('Fors',
                 'Vattenfall',
                 'Markerad vinterled',
                 'Fångstarm till led',
                 'Ruskmarkering',
                 'Tält- och eldningsförbud, tidsbegränsat',
                 'Skidspår')
```

I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125857/psql-variable-holding-text-with-multiple-lines) question for the multiline part. However

```
SELECT ('Fors',
        'Vattenfall',
        'Markerad vinterled',
        'Fångstarm till led',
        'Ruskmarkering',
        'Tält- och eldningsförbud, tidsbegränsat',
        'Skidspår') exclude_fell \gset
```

gives

```
ERROR:  column "fors" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (Fors,
                ^
```

, so I tried using triple quotes, dollar quotation and escape sequenses. Nothing has worked to satisfaction. This is true even if I use a single line variable and `\set`, so I must have misunderstood something about variable substitution. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: did you try using grave accent ( ` ) ?

Comment: @Roshan, how exactly are those used? Google tells me they have a function in psql, but not what they do.

Comment: You are trying *what* exactly? Which are your variables? How are those defined? What's the execution context? A shell? psql, SQL or PL/pgSQL? What are you trying to achieve and what version of psql / Postgres do you use?